# Log out Magento when browser was closed

Tags: php, magento

I've looked in several places, but the settings I found do not work, how can I log out the User as soon as he closed the browser?

Comment: you can't reliably detect when the user leaves your page, or closes the browser entirely. at best you can expire stale sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can be done via setting cookie lifetime set to 0 from magento admin.

```
System -> Configuration -> Web Tab ->Session Cookie management->Cookie Lifetime
```

Comment: That would also log out the user after each page visit.

Comment: It shouldn't @EdCottrell. `session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed."` from: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

Comment: Hi, @LuisÁvila, I tried your suggestion, but don't works. The user still log in.

Comment: Yes, you can. But first do what I said and, before testing it, logout and login again. Only then close the browser and return to the website. Let me know how it went